# Convert rows to columns with dynamic column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have two tables, one contains column names and second related data. I am trying to dynamically convert rows into columns. For now I have considered that all the columns will be included in final output but in actual scenario column names will be based on some pre-defined input.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TempTableData
go
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TempTableColumn
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.TempTableColumn
(
    ColumnId int CONSTRAINT PK_ColumnId PRIMARY KEY
    ,ColumnName varchar(512) NOT NULL
)
go
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TempTableColumn_ColumnName ON TempTableColumn(ColumnName) INCLUDE (ColumnId)
go

INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(1,'EmpId');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(2,'FirstName');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(3,'MiddleName');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(4,'LastName');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(5,'Age');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(6,'Gender');
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.TempTableData
(
    DataId int IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_DataId PRIMARY KEY
    ,GroupId int NOT NULL
    ,ColumnId int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_TempTableData_ColumnId REFERENCES TempTableColumn(ColumnId)
    ,ColumnValue varchar(8000)
)
go

INSERT INTO TempTableData(GroupId,ColumnId,ColumnValue) VALUES(101,1,'101'),(101,2,'John'),(101,4,'Grath'),(101,5,'40'),(101,6,'Male');
INSERT INTO TempTableData(GroupId,ColumnId,ColumnValue) VALUES(102,1,'102'),(102,2,'Smantha'),(102,4,'Fox'),(102,5,'35'),(102,6,'Female');
INSERT INTO TempTableData(GroupId,ColumnId,ColumnValue) VALUES(103,1,'103'),(103,2,'John'),(103,3,'M.'),(103,4,'Chang'),(103,5,'33'),(103,6,'Male');
go

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
                    FROM TempTableColumn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
--SELECT @cols [ColumnName]

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = N'SELECT GroupId,' + @cols + N' FROM 
             (
                SELECT td.GroupId,tc.ColumnName,td.ColumnValue
                FROM TempTableData td (nolock)
                    INNER JOIN TempTableColumn tc (nolock) ON (td.ColumnId = tc.ColumnId)
            ) x
            PIVOT
            (
                min(ColumnValue)
                FOR ColumnName in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p'
--SELECT @query
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

I tried above approach but final output isn't including all the records.

[image]

I don't think PIVOT / UNPIVOT is solution to this problem. Appreciate if someone could provide some inputs how to handle it.

After adding new column GroupId

[image]

Comment: Usual comment about the (ab)use of the `NOLOCK` hint (as it is clearly being abused here): [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: The problem is your design here, you have *nothing* that denotes what values belongs to who. Is "Smantha" for example, a 40 year of Female, or a 35 year old Male?

Comment: @Larnu you were right; added another column, GroupId, to denote the grouping, and PIVOT function is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Larnu said, avoid `NOLOCK` on your code.
Second, as @Larnu said too, you have no link between your data...

In a perfect world where your data link is the closeness in your table, based on `DataId` you can use this script to get what you want :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TempTableData
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TempTableColumn
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TempTableColumn
(
    ColumnId int CONSTRAINT PK_ColumnId PRIMARY KEY
    ,ColumnName varchar(512) NOT NULL
)
GO
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TempTableColumn_ColumnName ON TempTableColumn(ColumnName) INCLUDE (ColumnId)
--GO

INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(1,'EmpId');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(2,'FirstName');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(3,'MiddleName');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(4,'LastName');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(5,'Age');
INSERT INTO TempTableColumn(ColumnId,ColumnName) VALUES(6,'Gender');
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TempTableData
(
    DataId int IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_DataId PRIMARY KEY
    ,ColumnId int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_TempTableData_ColumnId REFERENCES TempTableColumn(ColumnId)
    ,ColumnValue varchar(8000)
)
GO

INSERT INTO TempTableData(ColumnId,ColumnValue) VALUES(1,'101'),(2,'John'),(4,'Grath'),(5,'40'),(6,'Male');
INSERT INTO TempTableData(ColumnId,ColumnValue) VALUES(1,'102'),(2,'Smantha'),(4,'Fox'),(5,'35'),(6,'Female');
GO

--SELECT * FROM TempTableColumn
--SELECT * FROM TempTableData

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
                    from TempTableColumn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
--SELECT @cols [ColumnName]
;
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @nb_col INT
DECLARE @i INT = 0
DECLARE @col_name VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @nb_col = COUNT(*) FROM TempTableColumn;

SET @sql =
'
WITH TMP ([Row],[ColumnId],[ColumnValue]) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ColumnId] ORDER BY [DataId]),[ColumnId],[ColumnValue] FROM TempTableData
)
SELECT'

WHILE @i < @nb_col
BEGIN
    SELECT @col_name = ColumnName FROM TempTableColumn WHERE ColumnId = @i+1
    IF @i != 0
        SET @sql = @sql + ','
    SET @sql = @sql + ' TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i+1) + '.ColumnValue AS ' + @col_name
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SET @i = 0
WHILE @i < @nb_col
BEGIN
    IF @i = 0
        SET @sql = @sql +
'
FROM TMP TMP1'
    ELSE
        SET @sql = @sql +
'
LEFT JOIN TMP TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i+1) + ' ON TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i+1) + '.[Row] = TMP1.[Row] AND TMP' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i+1) + '.ColumnId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i+1)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
SET @sql = @sql +
'
WHERE TMP1.ColumnId = 1'

PRINT(@sql)

EXEC(@sql)
```

The output :

| EmpId | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | John | NULL | Grath | 40 | Male |
| 102 | Smantha | NULL | Fox | 35 | Female |

Comment: Yes, I have updated my original question. Adding new column to show the relation helped.